# How to add attribute value in xml

Tags: c#, xml

i use this code for creating xml file using c# class.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            doc.AppendChild(docNode);
            XmlNode RootNode = doc.CreateElement("SDF");
            doc.AppendChild(RootNode);
            XmlAttribute rootAttribute2 = doc.CreateAttribute("Version");
            rootAttribute2.Value = "3.0";
            RootNode.Attributes.Append(rootAttribute2);
            XmlAttribute rootAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns:sdf");
            rootAttribute.Value = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
            RootNode.Attributes.Append(rootAttribute);
            XmlAttribute rootAttribute1 = doc.CreateAttribute("sdf:noNamespaceSchemaLocation");
            rootAttribute1.Value = "SDF.xsd";
            RootNode.Attributes.Append(rootAttribute1);
```

output of this code..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SDF Version="3.0" xmlns:sdf="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SDF.xsd">
```

but i want output like that

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SDF Version="3.0" xmlns:sdf="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" sdf:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SDF.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i searched on google and find answer that solve my problem

```
XmlNode RootNode = doc.CreateElement("SDF");
            doc.AppendChild(RootNode);
            XmlAttribute rootAttribute2 = doc.CreateAttribute("Version");
            rootAttribute2.Value = "3.0";
            RootNode.Attributes.Append(rootAttribute2);
            XmlAttribute newAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("sdf", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            newAttr.Value = "SDF.xsd";
            RootNode.Attributes.Append(newAttr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a [different overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs2zzesf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
XmlAttribute rootAttribute1 =
    doc.CreateAttribute("sdf", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", null);
```

Comment: this give an extra node.add an random value  output is <SDF Version="3.0" xmlns:sdf="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" d1p1:sdf="SDF.xsd" xmlns:d1p1="noNamespaceSchemaLocation">

Answer (score 1):

Use Overloaded version CreateAttribute method.

```
doc.CreateAttribute("name","namespaceURI")
```

See below link for detials.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlDocument.CreateAttribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: this give an extra node.add an random value output is              <SDF Version="3.0" xmlns:sdf="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; d1p1:sdf="SDF.xsd" xmlns:d1p1="noNamespaceSchemaLocation">on which bases it take d1p1